# How can I model a plane's trajectory in a simple way?

Tags: modeling

I would like to model a plane trajectory, here are my assumptions and conclusions so far:

Assumptions:

- we denote the plane's speed with $v(t)$, its trajectory $x(t)$, the total trajectory time will be $\tau$
- we have start and end times of flights as well as distance, so we have $\tau$ and $\int_0^\tau v(t)dt$
- the plane has an acceleration phase, let's call it $p_1$
- the plane has a plateau phase, $p_2$, where it reaches its cruise speed, $v_c$
- the plane has a deceleration phase, $p_3$.

The plane speed over time is
$v(t) = \begin{cases}
v_1(t) & t \in p_1 \\
v_c  & t \in p_2\\
v_2(t) & t \in p_3 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$

Let $p_1 = [0, t_1], p_2 = [t_1, t_2]$ and $p_3 = [t_2, \tau]$, we assume
$t_1 = \tau - t_2$ (essentially, same amount of time accelerate as to decelerate) and we rewrite $p_1 = [0, t_1], p_2 = [t_1, \tau- t_1]$ and $p_3 = [\tau-t_1, \tau]$.

We 'll now further assume $v_2(t) = v_1(t - \tau)$ (the deceleration shape is the inverted acceleration shape).

So at this point we are left with determining $v_1(t)$. The model has $m$ parameters for $v_1$ and $t_1$, $v_c$ (note that $t_1$ and $v_c$ can be included as a parameter in $v_1$).

My questions are:

- Are assumptions realistic, make sense, anything missing?
- How would you go about modelling $v_1(t)$

Possible answer 1:

Make the assumption that $v_1(t)$ is linear:
$v_1(t) = \frac{v_c}{t_1}t$.

The overall model has two parameters

Possible answer 2:

Go with a sigmoid-like function for $v_1$ but with a bounded input, I thought $\sin$ with the right phase would be good for this since it also has derivatives of zero at $\frac{dv_1(0)}{dt} = \frac{dv_1(t_1)}{dt} = 0$, this leads to:
$v_1(t) = v_c\frac{1-\cos{(\omega t)}}{2}$.

$\omega = 2\pi/t_1$

Again two parameters.

Since I don't want to have $v_c$ as a parameter/constant, I thought of introducing $\alpha = \frac{\omega}{v_c}$ thus

$v_1(t) = \frac{\omega}{2\alpha}(1-\cos{(\omega t)})$

Comment: I think the airspeed profile on ascent and on descent will be highly dependent on the aircraft type and, probably, fuel load. Also engine power will determine the ascent profile, nothing to do with the descent profile. Also I doubt velocities in these phases will be linear - there are all sorts of type-dependent limitations...

Comment: @Andy totally agree, I am just trying to figure out a simple model for being able to "predict" the speed and position of a commercial plane given its start and end points. I wanted to have feedbacks from the community and see if nice idea emerged from a simple model. I am fully aware that it makes very little physical sense and thanks for noting this  in your comment :)